# How to check values from list in DataFrame column and insert value by condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

for example, I have the next list:

```
l = ['a', 'x', 't']
```

and the DataFrame:

```
a = [{'suffix': 'a', 'qty': 5}, {'suffix': 'b', 'qty': 2}, {'suffix': 'c', 'qty': 7}, {'suffix': 'x', 'qty': 9}, {'suffix': 't', 'qty': 4}, {'suffix': 'p', 'qty': 1}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)
```

What I need, if values from list -> `l` are in column `df['suffix']` -> create new column `df['yes']` and put value from column `df['qty']`, else `df['yes'] = 0`

I need the next result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, probably something like this:

```
df['yes'] = df['qty'][df['suffix'].isin(l)]
df['yes'] = df['yes'].fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's what I need, and it is work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
from tokenize import String
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
l = ['a', 'x', 't']
a = [{'suffix': 'a', 'qty': 5}, {'suffix': 'b', 'qty': "ww"}, {'suffix': 'c', 'qty': "a"}, {'suffix': 'x', 'qty': "9"}, {'suffix': 't', 'qty': 4}, {'suffix': 'p', 'qty': 1}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a).assign(yes=lambda x: np.where(x["qty"].isin(l), x["qty"],0))
```

To also deal with text.

Comment: thanks for answer, but column df['qty'] it's only example, in this column can be str values

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```py
df['yes'] = df.suffix.isin(l) * df.qty
```

The boolean value returned by `isin()` for the `suffix` column will be converted to 0 for False, 1 for True, and multiplied by the value in `qty`.

Output:

```
  suffix  qty  yes
0     a    5    5
1     b    2    0
2     c    7    0
3     x    9    9
4     t    4    4
5     p    1    0
```